# ¿Diferencias entre nextInt y parseInt?

Tags: java

¿Diferencias entre nextInt y parseInt? Intento hacer un código que realice una resta a partir de dos numeros introducidos por teclado, el primer código es lo que yo he intentado hacer y el segundo código sería parte de la solución con  la que tengo duda.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

int numero1,numero2;
System.out.print ("Inserta dos numeros");
int numero1 = sc.nextInt;
int numero2 = sc.nextInt;
```

---

```
public static void main (String []args);
int n1,n2;
System.out.println("Escribe dos numeros enteros");
n1 = Integer.parseInt (System.console().readLine());
n2 = Integer.parseInt (System.console().readLine());
```

**¿Hacen lo mismo? ¿Son cosas distintas? Gracias de antemano.**

Comment: Hola anto. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. ¿Has mirado la documentacion de ambos metodos? Tras eso no deberias tener muchas dudas de las diferencias ya que son metodos bastente distintos. Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

El nextInt sirve para leer una variable en consola y el parseInt sirve para transformar un variable tipo String por ejemplo

```
string a= '123';

int b= Integer.parseInt(a); // Con esto convertiste a en b y podras manipular la cifra para alguna operación.
```

Answer (score 0):

Son distintos. No solo provienen de clases distintas Scanner y Integer... sino que el nextInt() lee un entero de la consola y ese es su objetivo primario. El parseInt toma un String y lo convierte en número entero.

Answer (score 0):

Son diferentes, en el caso de utilizar la clase Scanner te provee de métodos que puedes revisar en la documentación de JAVA(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) como por ejemplo:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
s.next();
sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLong();
```

estos ya te proveen la conversión del dato de entrada a un tipo especifico.

Mientras en el caso del método parseInt este recibe un tipo de dato String como parametro Integer.parseInt(String); en este caso el método System.console().readLine() lee la linea ingresada y pasa el dato en String a el método parseInt, esto quiere decir que con readLine() aunque tu ingreses 123 java lo crea como una cadena de texto(String) que debe ser convertida al tipo de dato de la variable en tú caso int, mientras el método sc.nextInt() ya realiza la conversión.

Otro punto a diferencia es la forma en la que leen los datos ingresados en consola por ejemplo:

Si tu ingresas  123 45 en la misma linea el método nextInt leerá primero 123 y luego cuando llames nuevamente nextInt le asignara 45.

```
123 45
numero1 = sc.nextInt; -> 123
numero2 = sc.nextInt; -> 45
```

y si utilizas readLine debes ingresar un número luego presionar la tecla enter y escribir el siguiente número no permite leer sobre la misma cadena de texto, con la clase Scanner puedes utilizar sc.nextLine() para realizar este mismo comportamiento.

Como recomendación deberías utilizar la clases Scanner cuando quieras leer datos desde consola ya que esta es mas Flexible y esta mejor preparada para este cometido.